# Looking for a really old novel where the people are geometric figures

Tags: story-identification, novel

A while ago I read about a really old science fiction novel/novella  (could have been more than a century old) where there weren't exactly people, but geometric figures in a 2-D world.

I think the protagonist (and maybe narrator) was a square and he visits the one dimension world. Later, his world is visited by a 3D geometric figure which takes him to the three dimensional world. The point was there are more dimensions than those the 2D-world figures knew.

That's all I can remember right now. Does anyone know the title of this novel?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

I presume that this would be "[Flatland: A Romance of Many Dimensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatland)" (written 1884 under the pseudonym "A.Square", real name Edwin Abbott Abbott).

Plot summary from wikipedia:

> The story describes a two-dimensional world occupied by geometric
>   figures, whereof women are simple line-segments, while men are
>   polygons with various numbers of sides. The narrator is a square, a
>   member of the caste of gentlemen and professionals, who guides the
>   readers through some of the implications of life in two dimensions.
>   The Square dreams about a visit to a one-dimensional world (Lineland)
>   inhabited by "lustrous points", and attempts to convince the realm's
>   monarch of a second dimension; but is unable to do so. He is himself
>   visited by a three-dimensional sphere, which he cannot comprehend
>   until he sees Spaceland (a tridimensional world) for himself. This
>   Sphere visits Flatland at the turn of each millennium to introduce a
>   new apostle to the idea of a third dimension in the hopes of
>   eventually educating the population of Flatland. From the safety of
>   Spaceland, they are able to observe the leaders of Flatland secretly
>   acknowledging the existence of the sphere and prescribing the
>   silencing of anyone found preaching the truth of Spaceland and the
>   third dimension. After this proclamation is made, many witnesses are
>   massacred or imprisoned (according to caste).
>
> After the Square's mind is opened to new dimensions, he tries to
>   convince the Sphere of the theoretical possibility of the existence of
>   a fourth (and fifth, and sixth ...) spatial dimension; but the Sphere
>   returns his student to Flatland in disgrace.

You can download the whole book for free here at [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/201).

Comment: They even made a film of it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eyuNrm4VK2w

Comment: If you liked Flatland you might enjoy [Flatterland: Like Flatland, Only More So](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17033.Flatterland) like I did.

Comment: Parodied in the Futurama episode "2-D Blacktop".

Comment: @22ndCenturyFza: The sequel "Sphereland" is also entertaining, as is Kee Dewdney's book "The Planiverse", which gives a more realistic look at a two-dimensional world.

Comment: He should have used the pseudonym E. A. Square;  Sheesh.

Comment: The pseudonym "A. Square" was a deliberate pun on "Abbott Abbott"; one must presume he felt that adding "E." would not improve the joke.

Comment: And for a modern Sci-Fi story, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatline_%28Doctor_Who%29